# Parse date from kendo-ui in french culture

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I try to parse a date into kendo and javascript.

```
var date = $("#Date").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
Globalize.parseDate(date._oldText);
```

and it worked fine in English culture but I am having a problem when culture set to French I got null

Answer (score 0):

First you must add all cuture lib references as described [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview#define-current-culture). So if you want work with more that one culture at same time, you must add all their libs.

Then you can use [`parseDate`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/parsedate) like:

```
parseDate((new Date()), 'fr-FR'); // Or whatever the culture should be
```

[Source](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview)

If you want to change the culture globally in the page context, use `kendo.culture("fr-FR")`.